# display records randomly one after another

Tags: php, sql, javascript

I want to display 5 records from a database with in a td one after another (about 60sec). How will i do this, with out the need of page refreshing? I don't know any idea about ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the contents of one cell be replaced continually? In that case, you have to use AJAX to retrieve your data and a timer to trigger this retrieval and contents change.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, have to use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use AJAX. You can put the content you want to refresh in an iframe, and the framed webpage will have a meta refresh header. This type of thing has been done for years before AJAX existed.

Answer (score 0):

by using you can achieve

Algorithm :

1. Create the td with some id.
2. Send the ajax request( for require time of interval )
3. Get the random rows from by ajax , and put the values 
   into that specific row id using innner.HTML
4. That's all it will work.

```
 If you want to know how to use ajax refer this below url
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp